# Difficult alphabetic sorting with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, sorting

I added a new entry type to my book, article and incollection functions called `abbreviation`. This way, dictionaries appear in the bibliography as my publisher wants them to appear :

> TLIO = Beltrami, Pietro G./Leonardi, Lino (dir.),Tesoro della Lingua Italiana delle Origini,Florence, CNR, 1998-., [URL = http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/TLIO].

My problem now is that, in the bibliography, these entries are sorted alphabetically by the author, not by the abbreviation:

> Casula Cant. Enn. = Antioco Casula,Boghes de Barbagia. Cantigos d’Ennargentu.ed.Giovanni Pirodda, Nuoro, Ilisso, 1999.
>
> Ax, Wolfram,Zellmer, E., Die lateinischen Wörter auf -ura, Indogermanische Forschungen, 82(1977), 302-307.
>
> TLIO = Beltrami, Pietro G./Leonardi, Lino (dir.),Tesoro della Lingua
>   Italiana delle Origini,Florence, CNR, 1998-., [URL =
>   http://tlio.ovi.cnr.it/TLIO].
>
> Buchi, Éva,Where Caesar’s Latin does not belong : a comparative
>   grammar based ap-proach to Romance etymology

I need my bibliography to consider the `abbreviation`  for the alphabetic sorting instead of the author, each time there is such an entry for a reference, but I don't know how to modify my bibliographystyle so that it will do this.

Any help would be very welcome !

A simplified version of my code is:

```
\documentclass[openany,ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[small]{dgruyter}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=french,italian, spanish, portuguese, latin, greek]{babel}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
Cf. \cite{DCECH}\\

\bibliographystyle{Bianca}
\bibliography{bibliographie}

\end{document}
```

And you can find my bibliographystyle here : [Bianca](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h28fwuo98rqignt/Bianca.bst?dl=0)

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/530154/5001) fix your issue?

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much, this is perfect !